# Paging files using REST api

Tags: rest

Can't seem to get paging working using the 2013 syntax:

```
_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test1/Documents')/Files?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=5&$top=1
```

The `top` parameter is working but not the `skiptoken`.

Answer (score 3):

#### There is no `skiptoken`, there is a `skip` *token* in the documentation

- URI Conventions (OData Version 2.0)
  http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/
- Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx

Search has different syntax

- SharePoint Search REST API overview
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8a4f7863-e4c1-4099-9189-a1894db36930%28office.15%29.aspx
- FAST Query Language (FQL) syntax reference
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394606.aspx

iREST iDOC

Comment: when using skip instead of skiptoken i get this error "The $skip expression "Paged=TRUE" is not valid."

Comment: Hmm.. then the Documentation where you read this syntax is wrong **??** ... weird... usually the manuals are correct, most of this has been around for 7 years or so. **Where did you read this syntax ??**

Comment: On several forums but there all talking about REST for sp 2013, im using sp 2016 online working with the new SPFX

Comment: So you now conclude Microsofts (2013) REST Documentation does not apply to 2016?

Comment: The second link you give specifies that SkipToken is the way to do paging, but that's only for some SharePoint OData sources, which the documentation doesn't specify

Comment: FYI: 3rd link for SP Search REST API now points to a Workflows Fundamentals page.

Answer (score 2):

_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('...')/Files doesn't support $skiptoken option use the standard $skip option

## SharePoint OData REST Queries has two "Skip" options for Paging

- $Skip
- $SkipToken

### $Skip

$Skip is the simple and standard OData way of implementing Paging it just specifies how many items to skip.

If you're paging 15 items/files/... at a time then you specify:

`$top=15&$skip=0` to get the page 1
`$top=15&$skip=15` to get the page 2
`$top=15&$skip=150` to get the page 11

#### Pros

- Standard OData so should work with any OData "sources"
- Simple
- You don't have to visit prior pages to get/calculate value

#### Cons

- Not "solid": Paging through list may

  - give same item on two pages if other item is inserted prior to it in used sort order
  - miss an item if other item is deleted prior to it in used sort order

### $SkipToken

The "solid" paging option implemented by some SharePoint OData "sources". The format of the token is complex and not something you should ever construct yourselves:

`$top=10&$skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_SortBehavior%3d0%26p_ID%3d10` to get page 2

Don't try to construct it yourselves. **Always** use href from `<link rel="next" ... />` from prior "page".

#### Pros

- "Solid": Items returned not depend on insert/delete of other items
- Implemented using standard REST link rel="next"

#### Cons

- Not working with a lot of OData "sources"
- You have to visit pages in order

Comment: $top doest work: 
The expression "web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test1/Documents')/Files$top=15&$skip=0" is not valid.
</m:message>
</m:error>

Comment: You're missing a ? in from of the querystring parameters: `web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test1/Documents')/‌​Files?$top=15&$skip=0‌​`

Comment: strill iget the files as i indicated in the top parameter but it always begin at the first file meaning the skip parameter have no effect.

Comment: $skip=0 means skip nothing have you tried $skip=15?

Comment: Yep i did, same result

Answer (score 0):

The skiptoken parameter in rest call works only on Lists/Libraries but not on relative path.
Try the following url it works

```
/sites/Test1/_api/web/getByTitle('Documents')/Items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=5&$top=5
```

Comment: i get "Cannot find resource for the request getByTitle"

Comment: use this syntax please, "/sites/Test1/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/Items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=5&$top=5"

Comment: what is p_ID in this?